# After create user on meteor, the session changes to the new user

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm creating my custom "Create User" page for meteor, everything is well and user is stored, but, after this, my actual session is changed by the new user. i.e. My Admin user is "admin" and when I create new user "foo", the session changes to "foo". I'm overriding Account.createUser for the initial run

This is my code

```
Template.usuarioNew.events
  'submit .form': (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    username = $('#username').val()
    name = $('#name').val()
    password = $('#password').val()

    roles = $('.role:checked')

    if roles.length == 0
      FlashMessages.sendWarning 'Escoge al menos un rol'
      return

    user =
      'username': username
      'password': password
      'profile':
        'name': name
      'roles': []

    roles.each (i) ->
      user.roles.push $(@).val()
      return

    Accounts.createUser user
    FlashMessages.sendSuccess 'Se ha creado un usuario'
    Router.go('/')

    return
```

And Accounts.onCreateUser

```
Accounts.onCreateUser (options, user) ->
  userProperties =
    profile: options.profile || {}
    roles: options.roles || []

  user = _.extend user, userProperties

  if !user.profile.name
    user.profile.name = user.username

  if !Meteor.users.find().count()
    user.roles.push 'admin', 'boss', 'specialist'

  user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior if you call `Accounts.createUser` from the client. As pointed out in [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser):

> On the client, this function logs in as the newly created user on successful completion. On the server, it returns the newly created user id.

The only way to insert a user without logging in as the newly created user is to initiate the creation process from the server. You can do this with a method call. In your `submit` callback, replace the call to `Accounts.createUser user` with:

```coffee
Meteor.call 'insertUser', user
```

Then on the server you can implement the method like this:

```coffee
Meteor.methods
  'insertUser': (user) ->
    check user, Match.ObjectIncluding
      username: String
      password: String
      profile: name: String

    Accounts.createUser user
```

The only problem is that you are sending the user's password to the server, which is only reasonable if you are using SSL. And even then, [may not be a great idea](http://heartbleed.com/)...

If you don't want to transmit the password, as the docs point out, you can create the user using the example above, but you will want to replace the `password` with an `email`, and then call [sendEnrollmentEmail](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_sendenrollmentemail) like so:

```coffee
Meteor.methods
  'insertUser': (user) ->
    check user, Match.ObjectIncluding
      username: String
      email: String
      profile: name: String

    userId = Accounts.createUser user
    Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail userId
```

Then you will need to create a route on the client which, when requested, makes a call to [resetPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_resetpassword) with the appropriate token and new password. Doing all this is more work for both you and the user but it's the most secure implementation that meets your requirements.